# Can you help me improve my decorator-based design?

Tags: uml

I have a small program to build a house. A house will have many floors (storeys), a storey can have many rooms, a room can contain many items. So I tend to use the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) for this program. Here is the initial design:

http://img337.imageshack.us/img337/5530/maina.jpg

Can you help me to improve the design?

Comment: I'm finding this funnier than I probably should be....

Comment: ConcreteRoom1 and ConcreteRoom2 ???

Comment: I've update the quiestion tags, as Java and Decorator pattern are absolutely not signifiant here, whereas design and uml should allow better replies.

Comment: @skaffman - if it's a joke than it is - not a bad one ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In object-oriented programming, the decorator pattern is a design pattern that allows new/additional behaviour to be added to an existing object dynamically.

This how [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) starts it's article on the decorator pattern.

So the decorator pattern is about adding behaviour to an existing object. And items in a room are not an additional behaviour for that room.

I think, the [Composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) would be a better choice to build a model for that domain.

(But if you still want a Decorator for your house you may find a better solution [here](http://www.yellowpages.com/) ;-) )

Answer (score 2):

I dont think decorator is the right pattern here. 
What I'm seeing the design is multiple instances of "is-a" and "has-a" relationships.

1. An "is-a" relation is a specialization. Examples :  "Bungalow" "is-a" "House", "ConcreteRoom1" "is-a" "Room".

   - "is-a" relationships are implemented using inheritance. In some cases, favoring composition over inheritance, "is-a" maybe implemented using decorators.
   - Ideally, the "Room" or "House" constructs must be interfaces (or abstract classes), which define object contracts and base properties
   - The concrete implementations of these interfaces are the actual objects that you will work with.
2. A "has-a" relationship is a composition. Examples : "House" has "Floors", "Room" has "Items"

   - Generally, a has-a relationship maybe implemented by storing attributes for each object that your class "has".
   - it is always a good idea to store the attributes as a collection of the interfaces - e.g. `Room` should have `List<Item> items`

Hope that clarifies the usage expected in your design.

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of inheritance here.  Decorator pattern dictates lesser inheritance and more composition.  So you create decorators and embellish your objects at runtime.  See [Decorator Patter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Comment: Or, you can use simple compositions between objects that define the real world scenario.  Like a House HAS stories, a storey HAS rooms, a room HAS items.  Inheritance seems useless here.  A storey does not inherit any behavior from a house....

Comment: indeed, prefere composition over inheritance :)